# How can i generate static api documentation for django rest APIs?

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I went through the documentation and tried to use swagger and coreapi, but both are interactive, I want the same api documentation without interaction. Is it possible?

Here you can see API documentation

https://editor.swagger.io/

but its interacting with the respective api. I want same UI and without interaction.

Comment: What do you mean by "static"? A PDF?

Comment: @dirkgroten just like drf schemaview...

Comment: Have you read [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/)? Btw you don't have to enable the 'try it out' feature in swaggerUI if that's what you mean by "interactive", you can also just use it as documentation without letting people try it out by submitting the forms.

Comment: what do you mean by "just like drf schemaview"? Can you show us an example of what you want by giving us a link?

Comment: @dirkgroten yeah, exactly, I want to get rid of that "try it out" button, I am using django-rest-swagger package, but i found nowhere instructions to disable it.

Comment: This is in the javascript config of [SwaggerUI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md), look at the option `supportedSubmitMethods`

Answer (score 2):

Oh it is really easy.

1. First install: django-rest-swagger==2.1.2
2. Add to settings: 'rest_framework_swagger'

Next make urls.py changes:

```
from rest_framework_swagger.renderers import SwaggerUIRenderer, OpenAPIRenderer
from rest_framework_jwt.authentication import JSONWebTokenAuthentication
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.renderers import CoreJSONRenderer
from rest_framework.schemas import get_schema_view

schema_view = get_schema_view(
    title='Swagger My - API documentation',
    public=True,
    renderer_classes=[CoreJSONRenderer, OpenAPIRenderer, SwaggerUIRenderer],
    authentication_classes=[JSONWebTokenAuthentication],
    permission_classes=[permissions.AllowAny]
)

urlpatterns = [
    # Swagger
    path('docs/', schema_view),
]
```

And you choose renderer_classes=[CoreJSONRenderer, OpenAPIRenderer, SwaggerUIRenderer].

This is example with JWT JSONWebTokenAuthentication for auth.

Comment: how to disable try it button while using get_swagger_view?